# How to set a formula in particular cells in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the following formula(its already working fine) in first 1000 rows in excel.Actually I am looking  in VBA. But, I am not familiar in VBA code.

**=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DD,HDR_COLMN,COLUMN(),0),"")**

**DD -** getting data from another sheet

**HDR_COLMN -** getting table header from another sheet(Sheet2) and showing as drop down values in Sheet1

Please any one can help me. Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky part is the double-quotes.

Say we want to deposit this with **VBA**

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B1:C10,2,TRUE),"")
```

This will do it:

```
Sub luxation()
    Range("A10").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B1:C10,2,TRUE),"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: And to apply that to the first 1000 rows, just do `Range("A1:A1000").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$10,2,TRUE),"""")"` (I mention this because it's not necessarily intuitive to a beginner, that the `.Formula` can work this way).

Comment: @Gary's Student and DavidZemens....Thanks . But I want to set this formula upto [A1 - A1000 to BB - BB1000]. (means a row contains 54 cells)

Comment: @Gary's Student and DavidZemens....Thanks . But I want to set this formula upto [A1 - to BB and upto A1000 to BB1000]. (means a row contains 54 cells) .Pls skip my previous comment. Thanks